# Let's consider a sphere of radius $R$ at $T_0=100$ C in a far field of water with temperature $T_\infty=30$ C

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, estimation

Let's consider a sphere of radius $R$ at $T_0=100$ C in a far field of water with temperature $T_\infty=30$ C.

How to calculate the sphere's temperature in each "layer" at any time?

I really don't know how to solve this problem,
I know the heat equation:
$$Q=mcT$$
$m$: is the object mass

$c$: Is the object specific heat

$T$: Is the object temperature change

and the Newton's Law of Cooling
$$\frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T-T_a)$$

where $k=\dfrac{\alpha S}{mc}$

$S$: is the object surface area

$\alpha$: Is the a constant

Comment: How long will it take for a sphere of radius RR at 1000 degrees in a medium of infinite water at a temperature of 30 degrees...**to do what**?

Comment: You are aware that 1000C is above the critical temperature of water, correct?

Comment: I'm actually not, it was the example given by the professor, but, what does it means?

Comment: Answer: forever.

Comment: Is it possible that your professor said or meant 100 C? Not many cooling media (other than air and various gases) will resist 1000 C.

Comment: I'm sure the professor said 1000 C, but your right so I'll change the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the initial temperature of the sphere is not 1000C, so that, at least, it is not above the critical temperature of water.  Let the initial temperature be $T_0$ and let $T_{\infty}$.  Let's also assume that the pressure is high enough so that the water close to the sphere does not boil.

My goal will be to arrive at an upper bound to the time for the average sphere temperature to drop to a given value.  So I will be neglecting natural convection heat transfer, and focusing entirely on stagnant conductive heat transfer.

The heat transfer coefficient at the surface of the sphere on the water side of the sphere surface will start off very high, and then gradually decrease to an asymptotic value at long times, given by $k_w/R$, where $k_w$ is the thermal conductivity of water and R is the outer radius of the sphere.  In a similar way, the heat transfer coefficient at the surface on the sphere material side of the boundary will also approach an asymptotic value at long times, given by $2k_S/R$, where $k_S$ is the thermal conductivity of the sphere material.

Based on these asymptotic values, the overall heat transfer coefficient between the water (far field) and the sphere will be given by:$$\frac{1}{U}=\frac{R}{k_w}+\frac{R}{2k_S}$$ 
Solving for U gives:$$U=\frac{2k_Sk_w}{R(2k_S+k_w)}$$
From a heat balance on the sphere, we have:
$$(\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3)\rho C_p\frac{dT}{dt}=-4\pi R^2U(T-T_{\infty})$$
Substituting our equation for the overall asymptotic heat transfer coefficient into this equation yields:$$\frac{dT}{dt}=-\frac{(T-T_{\infty})}{\tau}$$where $\tau$ is the characteristic cooling time, given by:
$$\tau=\frac{\rho C_p R^2(2k_S+k_w)}{6k_Sk_w}\tag{1}$$
Eqn. 1 for $\tau$ provides a value of the parameter $\alpha$ (or k) that was alluded to but not provided in the previous answers.

Comment: Interesting. Are you saying, within your caveats on heat transfer, that your $\tau$ is my $\alpha$? If so, it might help to use $\kappa$ instead of $k$ to avoid confusion.

Comment: It's actually the reciprocal of your alpha.

Comment: Yes, you are correct: $\tau=1/\alpha$, my bad.

Comment: By your procedure, I see that you're using this formula $V\rho C_p\dfrac{dT}{dt}=-AU(T-T_\infty)$, and if that's so, I would like to know which formula is it, so I can read about it, thanks.

Comment: If you would like to learn more on heat transfer analysis, see Transport Phenomena (a wonderful book) by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot.  There is a wealth of information in there.

Comment: How does the problem change if you consider a Cube instead a Sphere?

Comment: The problem is then much more complicated.  The sphere is strictly a 1D problem, but the cube would have to be handled 3D.

Comment: In a pinch (and I needed a quick answer), I would replace the cube with a sphere of the same volume.  The surface to volume ratio of a sphere is the same as that of a cube.  This would give a very crude approximation for the case of a cube, in terms of the average temperature as a function of time.

Comment: I have another question, what is the difference between this method and the method mentioned in the previous answer using partial differential equations? because it seems more complicated.

Comment: This method is an analytic approximation applicable for long times.  It is sufficiently  accurate if all you want a quick estimate is how long it takes for the sphere to essentially equilibrate.  If you want to know the details of how the temperature within the sphere is varying with radius and time at both long times and short times, you need to solve the pde's.  At long times, the solution to the pde's will approach the solution I presented.

Comment: Also, the pde's presented in the other answer does not address determination of the heat transfer coefficient on the water side of the interface.  To really do the problem right, you need to include a pde for that side of the interface as well.  Otherwise, you will be using my approximation for that side of the interface.

Comment: I can provide the derivation of those expressions I used for the long-time asymptotic heat transfer coefficients on the inside of the sphere and the water side of the interface, but I'm too lazy to do it because they are readily available in Carslaw and Jaeger, Conduction of Heat in Solids.  The one for water side of the interface, I knew by heart, but the one for the inside of the sphere, I rederived on my own.

Comment: Final comment:  If you want to see the complete solution to the pde's given in the other answer, plotted on a graph, see Heat Transmission by McAdams.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's Law of Cooling actually states:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=-kA[T(t)-T_a],$$
where $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ is the heat flux, $k$ the heat transfer coefficient, $A$ the sphere's surface area, $T(t)$ the sphere's temperature as a function of time and $T_a$ the ambient temperature (assumed constant).

When the sphere drops in temperature by $dT(t)$ then it loses an amount of heat $dQ$:

$$dQ=mcdT(t),$$

where $m$ is the mass of the sphere and $c$ the heat capacity of the sphere's material (assumed constant).

Combining we get:

$$\frac{mcdT(t)}{dt}=-kA[T(t)-T_a]$$

Reworked:
$$\frac{dT(t)}{T(t)-T_a}=-\alpha dt$$

With:

$$\alpha=\frac{kA}{mc}$$

Integrated between $t=0$, $T=T_0$ and $t$, $T$, we get:

$$\ln \frac{T-T_a}{T_0-T_a}=-\alpha t$$

So:

$$\large{T=T_a+(T_a-T_0)e^{-\alpha t}}$$

Note that only for $t \to \infty$ does $T \to T_a$.

Inversely we can write:

$$\large{t=\frac{1}{\alpha}\ln \frac{T_0-T_a}{T-T_a}=\frac{mc}{kA}\ln \frac{T_0-T_a}{T-T_a}}$$

This is the predicted temperature evolution, assuming the sphere's temperature is homogeneous at all times. Values for $k$ can be obtained from various thermal engineering websites.

Specifically for large spheres that is not true, as the core temperature will remain higher than the surface temperature and there's a radial temperature gradient $\frac{dT}{dR}$.

So with regard to:

> How to calculate the sphere's temperature in each "layer"? at any time

This derivation is [analytically much harder and can be found here](http://www.ekayasolutions.com/UCDMath/HeatCondSphere.pdf).

Basically a system of two simultaneous differential equations has to be solved:

$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=a \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r^2\frac{\partial T}{\partial r})$$

$$-b\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=h(T-T_a)$$

with $a$ the thermal diffusivity, $b$ the thermal conductivity and $h$ the heat transfer coefficient.

Comment: The document you you provided me seems to be what I need, however, I really don't understand the notation or the formulas, would you mind telling me me where can I find this subject, but totally explained? Thanks.

Comment: @GuadalupeAnimation - Hi. You won’t find an explanation of this complex problem that doesn’t rely on advanced calculus because that’s the language in which these problems are described and solved. You really need to ask yourself whether the simpler case (homogeneous sphere temperature) will not actually serve your purpose sufficiently well, as an approximation (for small spheres it will hold very well). At the very least, calculate the $T,t$ dependence for the simpler case, to see what that looks like and what kind of cooling time you obtain.

Comment: Please also note that the definitions of $k$ and $\alpha$ I use and the text uses are NOT the same.